# How to set maximum request time in uWSGI?

Tags: nginx, flask, wsgi, uwsgi

In Flask + uWSGI + nginx environment, I would like to set maximums request time. For example, if a request is taking more than 8 seconds, just abort the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `uwsgi` timeouts: [`harakiri`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#harakiri), [`socket-timeout`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#socket-timeout), [`http-timeout`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#http-timeout).